# determine between class and property constraint JSR303 bean validation

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am working on a generic plugin which help in validating beans based on JSR303 bean validation.
Since it need to be generic, so i can not rely on underlying vendor implementation.

I need to determine type of constraint violation from [ConstraintViolation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/beanvalidation/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html) object.
one way is to use `ConstraintViolation#getPropertyPath()`. If `getName()` returns null on the `leaf` node you have a class level constraint, otherwise a property level constraint.

One option is like

```
 Iterator<Node> violationNodes=violation.getPropertyPath().iterator();
    Node leafNode=null;
    while (violationNodes.hasNext()){
        leafNode=violationNodes.next();
    }

    if(leafNode!=null){
    // property constraint
    }
    else{
     // class constraint
    }
```

Is this good approach to determine or there can be other efficient or good approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Bean Validation 1.0, relying on `Node#getName()` would be the way to go (note that it should be `leafNode.getName() != null` in your if statement).

Bean Validation 1.1 adds a method `Node#getKind()` which returns an enumeration for the different element kinds, so this would be the preferable way if you work with 1.1 already.

Comment: Not sure as of now, since which version of `Bean Validation` to use dependents upon me, but i am not sure if all vendors are up with 1.1.If i recall properly, Apache Bean validator is still not up with 1.1